# Can the house in the image be built as a prefab? Can wool bricks be used in its construction?

Tags: materials

So I wanted to ask if a prefab can be built that looks like this house?

[image]

Also, can wool bricks be used in the house's construction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

This can be delivered as a set of wooden-framed walls all with completed wiring and pipework pre-fitted, as well as insulation and final internal wall finishes. Only some joints need painting.

A friend had one delivered like that, build from the foundations was 2 weeks.

There are companies that do this and I won't tell you the one he used as it may not be local to you. You can easily search for others as there are several. Try looking at the trade shows - they always are present there.

As for insulation it can be any material as long as its performance specs meet building regulations. We used "wood wool" as well as lamb's wool in ours, but we specified 30cm of insulation. A no-brainer between a small construction cost increase or lower heating bills for 40 years...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not really planning to build it, but it's more of a project I am trying to research on, but thanks a lot. Could you perhaps maybe say if it could be affordable or not, for research purposes?

Comment: Affordable? define? What I will say is that the one we built came out the same price as a concrete equivalent but requires less energy to heat (about a third).

Comment: By affordable I mean will it be affordable to buy a house like this, like can a middle-class person afford a house like this, and maybe if the lower-class person can afford it.